# Open CV Mat structure coordinates

Tags: c++, opencv

I am confused about the coordinates in OpenCV Mat structure. When I want to get a pixel I do something like this

```
 image.at<Vec3b>(i,j)
```

The question is whether (0,0) coordinate is the top-left corner coordinate. I'm not sure about that, because when I try to get (-100,-100) it still works and gets a pixel.

Comment: doing it with `(-100, -100)` may get undefined behavior, probably a segmentation error... You are trying to access a part of the memory that is not in the data array....

Comment: No, it returns a valid pixel. Something like (12,78,240). So it looks like an RGB pixel.

Comment: Maybe it went to another image data array... as I said before, is undefined behavior.... It may happen that in this case, in other cases it will give segmentation error and in other cases it will give you any other random data. [Here](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp#L916), you can see what is doing under the hood. As you can see in the release mode you are skipping all those asserts!! It should never be negative value, it works as a `uchar*`, which you should not use a negative index either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is the top-left.

From official documentation (for all pixel-access methods) [here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/user_guide/ug_mat.html) :

> the 0-based row index (or y-coordinate) goes first and the 0-based
>   column index (or x-coordinate) follows it

The `at(-100,100)` works because it is allowed to read (fast) everywhere in memory, but the data you get is not a pixel.

Comment: At least in the release version. The debug version of OpenCV checks if your coordinates are in range and throws an exception if they are not.

Comment: The data I get looks like a valid pixel, because the intensities of all three channels are in the range from 0 to 255. At the same time, when I try to get (-1000, 1000), for example, it throws an exception. So that means that it validates the coordinates somehow.

Comment: May it be pixels from another image ? (stored near from the one you want access to)

Comment: @Pierre, maybe. However, that's bad that there are no proper validations.

Comment: @MaxTsylko : I agree, I have had the same problem than yours :)
It is justified for performance issues (here : http://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#aa5d20fc86d41d59e4d71ae93daee9726)

Comment: the value will always look like it's betwen 0 and 255 because only a single byte is read for each pixel. The behaviour occurs because there are two cases if you accidentally try to access memory that doesn't belong to your image: 1. the memory address is used by your program, then the OS doesn't know whether you wanted to access the memory address or not, then the program won't crash and you don't recognize that the value doesn't belong to your image and isn't really a pixel (very dangerous).

Comment: 2. the memory address you accidentally access does belong to a different program, then the OS knows that the memory doesn't belong to the program which accesses it. In that case it will generate a segmentation fault.